# Using variables from other modules in user created classes - VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, variables, scope

I have created some custom class - Class1 to change the click event of CommandButton control. How can I pass variables/value from/to other modules, say `UserForm1.Listbox1.List(index)`? is it ok to use `UserForm1.Listbox1.List(index)` within the Click event of Class1? Let's say, if I have variable x declared on UserForm1 can I use it as `UserForm1.x`, or have to declare as Public on both modules? 
Of course, I can use trial and error method and make it work, but I want to know best practices? Can someone share resources or recommendations?

Class1

```
Public WithEvents ButtonEvent As MsForms.CommandButton

Private Sub ButtonEvent_Click()

End Sub
```

Comment: You are discussing adding a property to a Class so try looking up the MS help on VBA properties. Once you have implemented a property you will be able to use that property on an instance of the class just like a normal variable.

Comment: I'm currently reading up on [this cpearson.com page about Classes in VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Classes.aspx). Might help guide you in the right direction?